# Using regex to detect ONLY double braces

Tags: python, regex

I wrote some code to grab everything between two curly braces along with the braces themselves

```
strings = re.findall('\{{.*?\}}',string)
```

However if the string contains mismatched brackets e.g "John is from {{city},{{country}}" this does not work correctly.

Is there a way to adjust my code so that I can only grab the matched brackets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply exclude the braces from the "contained string" with a character class:

```
strings = re.findall(r'\{\{[^{}]*\}\}', string)
```

Comment: I don't think you need to escape the brackets either. +

Comment: @JvdV Nor do I think it hurts to do so. IIRC braces are special characters and I prefer erring on the side of caution.

Comment: This doesn't work correctly when there are single braces inside of double braces. For example, `{{a string}}` matches, but`{{f"a {variable} in an f-string"}}` doesn't

Comment: @Expurple The OP didn't decide for all these "edge" cases.